# Handle excluded element in a foreach

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

In first template, I am intentionally excluding an element ('milk') because the parsed data map is relatively flat and I would like to use XSLT to categorize and structure the data. The aim is to process the excluded element ('milk') in the second template. The both templates works running them one at a time. Running the templates together will not show the result of the excluded element ('milk') which should set another attribute name and attribute value.

**JSON:**

```
<data>
{
  "storage": {
    "pencils": 12,
    "milk": 8,
    "rulers": 4
  }
}
</data>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:transform
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:storage="http://www.exammple.com/1"
  xmlns:office="http://www.exammple.com/2"
  xmlns:item="http://www.exammple.com/3"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <!-- Parse JSON to XML -->

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <storage:one>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)"/>
    </storage:one>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Print map -->
  <!-- <xsl:template match="*[@key = 'storage']"> <xsl:copy-of select=".."/> </xsl:template> -->

  <xsl:template match="*[@key='storage']">

      <xsl:for-each select="*[not(@key='milk')]">
      <xsl:element name="item:{@key}">
        <xsl:attribute name="office">plant-1</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[@key='milk']">
      <xsl:for-each select=".">
      <xsl:element name="item:{@key}">
        <xsl:attribute name="beverage">plant-2</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<storage:one xmlns:item="http://www.exammple.com/3"
             xmlns:office="http://www.exammple.com/2"
             xmlns:storage="http://www.exammple.com/1">
   <item:pencils office="plant-1">12</item:pencils>
   <item:rulers office="plant-1">4</item:rulers>
</storage:one>
```

**Wanted result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<storage:one xmlns:item="http://www.exammple.com/3"
             xmlns:office="http://www.exammple.com/2"
             xmlns:storage="http://www.exammple.com/1">
   <item:pencils office="plant-1">12</item:pencils>
   <item:rulers office="plant-1">4</item:rulers>
   <item:milk beverage="plant-2">8</item:milk>
</storage:one>
```

Comment: To me it seems you are making your life difficult by mixing templates and apply-templates with nested for-each. Why don't you try to write templates and rely on apply-templates only. And as said before, doing `for-each select="."` is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second template is never matched, because it is never reached. All elements are processed by `<xsl:template match="*[@key='storage']">` - which doesn't have an `<xsl:apply-templates ...>` to reach further templates.

Your first template does not recurse into its children. So add an `<xsl:apply-templates select="*" />` to the end of the first template:

```
    <xsl:template match="*[@key='storage']">
      <xsl:for-each select="*[not(@key='milk')]">
        <xsl:element name="item:{@key}">
          <xsl:attribute name="office">plant-1</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:template>
```

This will try to apply further templates at the level of "storage" and therefore match the second template.

Answer (score 1):

I would write templates for each different output type and if the order of the output is different from the order of the input throw in an `xsl:sort` or an XPath 3.1 `sort` call to change the order:

```
  <xsl:template match="data">
    <storage:one>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)"/>
    </storage:one>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[@key = 'storage']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="sort(*, (), function($el) { $el/@key = 'milk' })"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[@key='storage']/*[not(@key='milk')]">
      <xsl:element name="item:{@key}">
        <xsl:attribute name="office">plant-1</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[@key='storage']/*[@key='milk']">
      <xsl:element name="item:{@key}">
        <xsl:attribute name="beverage">plant-2</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```